# abcpdf.dll crashes IIS on windows 2019 server

Tags: .net, iis, windows-server-2019, abcpdf

Windows 2019 server
.NET framework 3.5

When I call **byte[] theData = myDoc.GetData();** in page load in my web app, IIS dies without a trace.

I have this call inside a **try - catch block**, but the exception is never thrown, IIS dies, and it needs an **iisreset** command to serve web pages again.

I tried to get the version with **myDoc.GetInfo(0, "ABCpdfVersion")**, but this returns an empty string.  Properties on the ABCpdf.dll show product version 3.0.0.24776

of course, the web app runs now "on my box".  At first it failed when I ran visual studio without elevated permissions, but when I ran as admin it produced the PDF page.  After running as admin on my box, it now works without said admin permissions.

I am thinking that a registry item needs to be created with admin permissions, which can then be modified with normal user permissions, but this is just a guess.  I tried setting the app pool to IUSR without success.

Any insight to this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks folks.

Comment: You can try to debug the cause using IIS [Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.